# Why call have code 400 on response when postman doing it correct?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to provide clear code in accordance with the guidelines architecture and CleanCode rules.

I tried to use gson library to serialize data used in retrofit call.

I know that i can use @SerializedName in my model class but i want to learn how to use gson builder.

In MainActivity i have:

```java
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CredentialModel credentials = new CredentialModel("User", "Password");
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
                String json = gson.toJson(credentials);
                UserApiClient userApiClient = RetrofitInstace.getRetrofitInstance().create(UserApiClient.class);
                Call<String> call = userApiClient.login(json);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                        toastNotify(String.valueOf(response.code()));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        toastNotify("Fail");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Interface UserApiClient:

```java
@POST("/api/AppUser/login")
    Call<String> login(@Body String credentials);
```

RetrofitInstance class:

```java
public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(new OkHttpClient())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

I receive 400 error code when postman with data coppied from json variable in debug mode to body give me code 200. It isn't my serwer so i can't tell what is done on server side. Also im new in android and don't know how to check raw request in android studio yet.

Comment: Viewing the raw request is the easiest way to debug these kinds of errors. I'm not very familiar with Android, but if you could review the raw request right before you make it, you might get some insight into what's going wrong. If you can't see it when it goes out the door on Android, maybe you can up the logging on your API and see what it's receiving. Rule of Thumb: if you can get it to work in postman but not your app, you aren't sending what you think you're sending.

Comment: You can debug your network state with proxy tools like [charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), i suspect the reason is the escape character. Your Json String may be transform from `{"key":"value"}` to `{\"key\": \"value\"}` or something like that. Just suspect

Comment: @Magic you had right, but i don't know why.

Comment: @Kamil Could you past a screen shot when you request with postman? And debug with Android Studio watch the variable in Android Studio Debug window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `GsonConverterFactory.create()` but you're passing String at `Call<String> login(@Body String credentials);` . You can't do that.

You need to pass in a POJO that is serialized by gson. Or else retrofit will pass in a null object as the body.

```
class MyBody {
    // serialize it here
}

// You also cannot use a String at Call<String>
// for now use ResponseBody. Create a POJO class later though
Call<ResponseBody> login(@Body MyBody credentials);
```

What you want to do is already being done inside retrofit.

```
// retrofit does this for you underneat when you use GsonConverterFactory.create()
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
String json = gson.toJson(credentials);
```